# Mechanism for chloromethylation of benzene with formaldehyde and HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

[image: Overall reaction]

What is the mechanism of the above reaction? I have thought of one possibility:

[image: proposed mechanism]

Would this work? How exactly is the chlorine installed on the alkyl chain?

Comment: The actual mechanism turns out to be in different order when you use ZnCl2 instead of AlCl3. It is probably the same case here. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanc_chloromethylation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This reaction is chloromethylation, similar to [Blanc chloromethylation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanc_chloromethylation), but using $\ce{AlCl3}$ as co-catalyst instead of $\ce{ZnCl2}$. These are reactions belonging to a group related to Friedel-Crafts reactions, but characterized by usage of protonation instead of coordination with molecular Lewis acids

Mechanism of your reaction (not accounting for influence of co-catalyst) can be written as:

[image]
([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/ChloromethylationMechanism.png))

$\ce{AlCl3}$ coordinates to $\ce{HCl}$ creating adduct ($\ce{HAlCl4}$) which is much stronger acid.